# WebSVN with 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, apache2, repository

I want to install WebSVN on 18.04 LTS. It seems that WebSVN is currently *out of support*. On Debian Stretch, one needs to enable the oldstable repo.

Which repo supports WebSVN for Ubuntu 18.04, and how can I enable that repo?

Comment: fyi:  debian stretch (9) is debian old-stable;  debian buster (10) = stable, so old-stable is debian-9 (stretch).   Your instructions to need old-stable are likely *out-of-date* themselves (*and it's now OLD-OLD-stable or 8/Jessie which is nearing EOL*)  - https://www.debian.org/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Debian 8 and Ubuntu 18.04 were the last repositories to include websvn in a package.

Fortunately websvn is still being maintained and it's not too difficult to install. You only need PHP with XML support.

Start by creating an apache config file /etc/apache2/conf-available/websvn.conf

```
Alias /websvn /var/www/websvn
<Directory /var/www/websvn>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Install PHP with XML support, checkout websvn and enable the apache config you just created:

```
sudo apt-get install php php-xml
cd /var/www
svn checkout https://github.com/websvnphp/websvn.git/tags/2.5/ websvn
sudo a2enconf websvn
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Point your browser at the websvn directory. You should be told to create the configuration file /var/www/websvn/include/config.php

I added the following lines to my config.php

```
$config->setEnscriptPath('/usr/bin');
$config->setSedPath('/bin');
$config->parentPath('/var/svn-repos');
$config->useEnscript();
```

This tells websvn where to find sed and enscript, and that my repositories are linked from /var/svn-repos/

I installed websvn on an existing server, so there may be additional dependencies. Check /var/log/apache2/error.log if your browser receives a 500 error.